# Knockout errors with containerless control flow syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm still new to knockout, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. I have an html form with dynamic input controls which can be added by the user. I don't know if the problem is caused by the containerless control flow syntax, but I don't know how I can achieve the same result without it.

The markup for the dynamic part is this:

```
  //begin form

  <!-- ko foreach: durationValues -->
      <div class="form-group">
          <!-- ko if: ($index() === 0) -->
              <label for="Values[0].Value">Values</label>
          <!-- /ko -->
          <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: text, attr: { name: 'Values[' + $index() + '].Value' }" data-val="true" data-val-required="Value required." />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <!-- ko if: ($index() === 0) -->
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" data-bind="click: addDurationValue"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add</button>
                  <!-- /ko -->
                  <!-- ko if: ($index() > 0)-->
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.removeDurationValue"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove</button>
                  <!-- /ko -->
              </span>
          </div>
          <span class="field-validation-valid invalid-feedback" data-bind="attr: { 'data-valmsg-for': 'Values[' + $index() + '].Value' }" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>
  <!-- /ko -->

  //endform
  //jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-validate-unobtrusive, bootstrap and knockout script files loaded

  <script>
  function DurationValue(text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    function DurationValuesViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.durationValues = ko.observableArray([
            new DurationValue("")
        ]);

        self.addDurationValue = function () {
            self.durationValues.push(new DurationValue(""));

            //Remove current form validation information
            $("form")
                .removeData("validator")
                .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");

            //Parse the form again
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
        };

        self.removeDurationValue = function (durationValue) { self.durationValues.remove(durationValue); };
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new DurationValuesViewModel());
  </script>
```

The page keeps yelling me these errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError:
>
> Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return durationValues }"
>
> Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return ($index() === 0) }"
>
> Message: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return addDurationValue }"
>
> Message: addDurationValue is not defined
>       at click (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:2992), :3:58)
>       at newValueAccessor (knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:4231)
>       at init (knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:4241)
>       at init (knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:4234)
>       at knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:3368
>       at Object.ignore (knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:1480)
>       at knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:3367
>       at Object.arrayForEach (knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:159)
>       at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:3353)
>       at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout-3.4.2.debug.js:3233)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your containerless control flow syntax is fine. But, you need to add `$parent` or `$root` before the `addDurationValue` used in `click` binding function to provide proper [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

Inside the `foreach` binding, knockout looks for `addDurationValue` in each `DurationValue` object rather than the `DurationValuesViewModel` instance. So, we need to specify where to look for the function. In this case, `$root` and `$parent` refer to the same object.

```js
function DurationValue(text) {
  this.text = text;
}

function DurationValuesViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.durationValues = ko.observableArray([
    new DurationValue("")
  ]);

  self.addDurationValue = function() {
    self.durationValues.push(new DurationValue(""));

    //Remove current form validation information
    $("form")
      .removeData("validator")
      .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");

    // Commented for now
    //Parse the form again
    // $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
  };

  self.removeDurationValue = function(durationValue) {
    self.durationValues.remove(durationValue);
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new DurationValuesViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko foreach: durationValues -->
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- ko if: ($index() === 0) -->
  <label for="Values[0].Value">Values</label>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: text, attr: { name: 'Values[' + $index() + '].Value' }" data-val="true" data-val-required="Value required." />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
          <!-- ko if: ($index() === 0) -->
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.addDurationValue"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add</button>
          <!-- /ko -->
          <!-- ko if: ($index() > 0)-->
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.removeDurationValue"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove</button>
          <!-- /ko -->
      </span>
  </div>
  <span class="field-validation-valid invalid-feedback" data-bind="attr: { 'data-valmsg-for': 'Values[' + $index() + '].Value' }" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Worked like a charm and fixed all errors, thank you!